# C++ When does class object file get compiled?

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to C++, and having difficulty understanding the steps of class object files getting created and compiled.

Let's say I create 3 files: 1. class header file 2. class cpp file (member function definitions present) 3. main cpp file

/*
When I run the main cpp file which includes the class header file (say as "#include class.h"), when does class cpp file get compiled, object file created, and linked?

The reason why I'm having difficulty is that from the compiler point of view, when it sees the main cpp file, there is only the header definition, no member function definition. However, even in the class header file, there is no class cpp file included. How would compiler know to run the class cpp file when it is not referred to in either class header file and the main cpp file?
*/

Let me clarify my question.
// Maybe I've said things I don't even understand lol.

So, basically I'm trying to run a main function in a say 'main.cpp' file. This 'main.cpp' file includes the 'class.h' header (include "class.h"). How would compiler execute the functions defined in header file when member function is not declared in 'class.h?' All my member function declaration is in 'class.cpp,' which is not included in 'class.h' or 'main.cpp.'

Comment: There is no such a thing like "class object file" AFAIK in c++, at least not specifically. Also, you don't "run cpp files". And to understand your issue, how do you compile a project with two "cpp" files? Because it is all the same, it doesn't matter if there are classes, you can have a `cpp` with a definition of only one function.

Comment: @luk32 Example: `Rectangle.h` is included in `Rectangle.cpp`, `Rectangle.cpp` is compiled and `Rectangle.obj` is created. I think that's the "class object file" OP is referring to.

Comment: @GrinNare Update (Edit) your question adding that comment, and remove that comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're using an IDE, since you mention running cpp files - compilers don't know how to run anything.

Your IDE manages these dependencies for you.
When you press "Run", the IDE will decide which files in your project need compiling, and when the compilation is done it will link all the object files together.
If compilation and linking succeeded, the IDE then launches the executable program.

If you want a better understanding of the concepts, step away from your IDE and do all your compilation and linking on the command line for a while.
(It's not complicated, only tedious.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I said I'm new to C++ and a lot of things are new.
I guess IDE you are mentioning is the 'Xcode' that I'm using.
So this program will deliver the files to compiler, link the object file, and launch executable program for me, correct?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile every `.cpp` file. Headers; `.h` files, are just for declarations, means that to let the compiler determine if you use the functions correctly. Each `.cpp` contains code and should be translated to machine code (`.o` files). After all these compilations, you need to link them to build the executable so that every function used is contained in the same file. The following commands can help you (using `g++` compiler):

```
$ g++ -c myclass.cpp            // produces the myclass.o file
$ g++ -c main.cpp               // produces the main.o file
$ g++ -o myapp main.o myclass.o // produces the myapp executable
```

This is oversimplified for the sake of understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I understand the process. However, it leads me to another question.
Is there different kinds of C++ compilers from different manufacturer or is it built in for every computers?
Based on  your comment 'g++ compiler,' I guess there are not just one compiler but many.

Comment: Yes there is many. The two common ones are the `gcc` suite and `Visual` from Microsoft, both in different versions. But there exists many others. `xcode` uses `llvm/gcc`.